# Css @media for both mobile devices and max-width desktop window

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

Practically I have an web widget that should transform when the window width is less than `max-width` attribute.

This should work for both mobile devices and a re-sized desktop browser window.

I have tried these scenarios

```
   /* works only for mobile devices but not for re-sized desktop window */
   @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) { ... } 

   /* works only for re-sized desktop but not for mobile devices */
   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { ... } 

   /* works only for re-sized desktop window but not for mobile devices*/
   @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px), (max-width: 768px) { ... }
```

Is there a way to achieve same behavior for both mobile devices and a desktop browser window that has a width smaller than 768px ?

Comment: Have you added the viewport meta element to your HTML?

Comment: @media screen and (max-device-width: 768px) { ... } use this

Comment: @ralph.m that was what I was missing, please create an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Yeah right the Viewport meta tag -- don't live home without it. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this it will work on mobiles as well as window

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 768px) {
... 
}
```

and meta tag in header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you add this code before head or after title ?

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the below meta tag to your html head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and below is the mediaquery which will give you the result for responsive layout below 768 width in both browser and mobile devices.

```
/*Mobile Portrait and  Landscape*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { .. }
```

If you want to see the responsive behavior in your IE 6-8 browser also then you require to attach respond.js to your html head section, below is the link where you can download it.

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Thanks,
Mohsinali Chidi.